# Ajax call with Laravel Form

Tags: ajax, laravel

Hello can someone please help me because I wanted to use ajax in my laravel form, when everytime I hit 'CREATE POST' button, the table contains all my posts will hide and then the form will show, and when clicking the submit button in the form the table will then show with its new data inserted below the table and the form will hide. I have a code but it is not working.

**Controller** Code:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //validate the data
    $this->validate($request, array(
        'title'       => 'required|max:255',
        'slug'        => 'required|alpha_dash|min:5|max:255|unique:posts,slug',
        'category_id' => 'required|integer',
        'body'        => 'required',
        'featured_image' => 'image|nullable|max:1999'
    ));

    //store in the database
    $post = new Post;

    $post->title = $request->title;
    $post->slug  = $request->slug;
    $post->category_id = $request->category_id;
    $post->body  = Purifier::clean($request->body);

    //Save Our Image
    if ($request->hasFile('featured_image')) {
        $image = $request->file('featured_image');
        $filename = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $location = public_path('images/'. $filename);
        Image::make($image)->resize(800, 400)->save($location);

        $post->image = $filename;
    } 
    $post->save();
    return response()->json($post);


    // Session::flash('success', 'The blog post was succesfully saved!');

    // //redirect to another page
    // return redirect()->route('posts.show', $post->id);

}
```

**Route**:

```
Route::resource('/posts', 'PostController');
Route::post('/addpost', 'PostController@store');
```

**Form** Code:

```
        {!! Form::open(['id' => 'form-post', 'method' => 'POST', 'route' => 'posts.store', 'data-parsley-validate' => '', 'files' => true]) !!}

        {{ csrf_field() }}

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="title">Title:</label>
                <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" data-error="Please enter title." required />
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="title">Slug:</label>
                <input type="text" name="slug" class="form-control" data-error="Please enter title." required />
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>


            {{ Form::label('category_id', 'Category') }}
            <select id="add-category" class="form-control" name="category_id">
                    @foreach($categories as $category)
                        <option value='{{ $category->id }}'>{{ $category->name }}</option>
                    @endforeach 
            </select>

           {{ Form::label('featured_image', 'Upload Featured Image:', ['class' => 'form-spacing-top']) }}
           {{ Form::file('featured_image',["id" => 'add-image', "class" => 'form-control-file']) }}


          {{ Form::label('body', 'Post Body:') }}
          {{ Form::textarea('body', null, array('id' => 'add-body', 'class' => 'form-control')) }}

          {{ Form::button('Create Post', array('id' => 'submit-post', 'class' => 'btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block', 'style' => 'margin-top: 20px;'))}}
        {!! Form::close() !!}

    </div>
</div>
```

**Ajax** Code:

```
    $(document).on('click', '.create-post', function() {
        $('.create-form').css('display','block');
        $('.posts-table').css('display','none');
    });

    $('#submit-post').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var action = $('#form-post').attr('route');
        var title = $("#form-post").find("input[name='title']").val();
        var slug = $("#form-post").find("input[name='slug']").val();
        var category_id = $("#add-category").val();
        var featured_image = $("#add-image").val();
        var body = $("#add-body").val();


        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url : "/addpost",
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN' : $('input[name="_token"]').val()
            },
            data : {
                title: title, 
                slug: slug, 
                category_id: category_id, 
                featured_image: featured_image, 
                body: body
            },
            success: function(data){
                $('.create-form').css('display','none');
                $('.posts-table').css('display','block');
                $('.table tbody').append("<tr id='" + data.id + "' class='item'><th>" + data.id + "</th><td>" + data.title + "</td><td>" + data.body + "</td><td>date</td><td><button class='show-modal btn btn-success' data-id='" + data.id + "' data-title='" + data.title + "' data-slug='" + data.slug + "' data-category='" + data.category_id + "' data-image='" + data.featured_image + "' data-body='" + data.body + "'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open'></span> Show</button><button class='edit-modal btn btn-info' data-id='" + data.id + "' data-title='" + data.title + "' data-slug='" + data.slug + "' data-category='" + data.category_id + "' data-image='" + data.featured_image + "' data-body='" + data.body + "'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span> Edit</button><button class='delete-modal btn btn-danger' data-id='" + data.id + "' data-title='" + data.title + "' data-slug='" + data.slug + "' data-category='" + data.category_id + "' data-image='" + data.featured_image + "' data-body='" + data.body + "'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span> Delete</button></td></tr>");
                console.log(data); 
            }


        });

    });
```

Comment: where do you have problem? Which section is not working? What is the error?

Comment: this is my error . Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 422 (Unprocessable Entity). And Also When I hit the submit button, nothing happens

Comment: probabily there is validation error.. add a `return 'faield';` statement before validation in the controller and check does that returns properly.

Comment: check your request and your DB field.. maybe the error because of the name of field db does not match with the model field name

Comment: When I try to put a data in the form without putting an image on it, my data will save in the database and it is working. I think my problem here is my image upload field.

Answer (score 0):

It's not enough information about the error.
Try `dd()` in your controller & check it in [F12 -> Network].

And since you're using ajax to sending request, there no need to define options (action, route) in Form. remove it.